# mongoose save() not saving data but empty array with objectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**mongoose not saving**
and returns a empty object

my code is shown below

**schema**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name:{type:String},
  age:{type:Number}
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('E-commerse',userSchema)
```

**save code**

```
exports.addUser =async (req,res) => {
  try{
    var newUser = new userSchema({
    name:req.body.name,
    age:req.body.age
  })
 DBdata = await newUser.save()
    res.json({status:"success",data:DBdata})
  }catch(err){
    res.json({status:'failed',err}).status(500)
  }
 
}
```

when i look in postman i got result as like this

```
{
    "status": "failed",
    "err": {
        "code": 79,
        "codeName": "UnknownReplWriteConcern",
        "errInfo": {
            "writeConcern": {
                "w": "majority/e-commerce",
                "wtimeout": 0,
                "provenance": "clientSupplied"
            }
        },
        "result": {
            "n": 1,
            "electionId": "7fffffff0000000000000054",
            "opTime": {
                "ts": {
                    "$timestamp": "7099642676147912705"
                },
                "t": 84
            },
          
}
```

can enyone please solve it

Comment: Can you post the structure of the URI that you are using to connect to MongoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is connect fail to database

1. check your connect URI
2. make sure you're connected to db
3. update your question please